# Update else Insert - expects parameter which was not supplied error

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert, if-statement

Thank you for your patience... I'm not an expert in SQL and appreciate your help. 
Using SQL Server 2005

Two tables - `Leads` and `Meetings`. I'm trying to update/create a record using If Exists Update else Insert.

I have a `Leads_ID` column in the `Meeting` table and use that to check if the lead has a record in the meeting table, if it does update otherwise insert.

Running this SP I get the 'expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied' error, but I'm passing the ID, aren't I?

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[leadfollowup]
  @ID AS NVARCHAR(55),
  @NAME AS nvarchar (50)
 AS
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MEETINGS WHERE LEADS_ID = @ID)
 BEGIN 
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE MEETINGS SET name = (SELECT TOP 1 FIRST_NAME FROM LEADS ORDER BY DATE_MODIFIED DESC)
  WHERE  LEADS_ID = @ID

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0

 INSERT INTO MEETINGS (LEADS_ID,NAME) 
 SELECT TOP 1 L.ID, first_name +' '+Last_name +' 'as NAME
 FROM LEADS_CSTM lc
 JOIN LEADS l on l.id = lc.id_c WHERE FOLLOW_UP_DATE_C >getdate()
 ORDER BY l.date_modified Desc
END
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[leadfollowup]
  @ID AS NVARCHAR(55),
  @NAME AS nvarchar (50)
 AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 IF EXISTS(SELECT LEADS_ID FROM MEETINGS WHERE LEADS_ID = @ID)
     BEGIN 

      UPDATE MEETINGS SET name = (SELECT TOP 1 FIRST_NAME FROM LEADS ORDER BY DATE_MODIFIED DESC)
      WHERE  LEADS_ID = @ID

     END
 ELSE
     BEGIN

     INSERT INTO MEETINGS (LEADS_ID,NAME) 
     SELECT TOP 1 L.ID, first_name +' '+Last_name +' 'as NAME
     FROM LEADS_CSTM lc
     JOIN LEADS l on l.id = lc.id_c WHERE FOLLOW_UP_DATE_C >getdate()
     ORDER BY l.date_modified Desc

     END
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm reading your proc correctly, your logic is

If there's a row in the meeting table that matches on leads id equal to the parameter, we're going to do "a bunch of junk". There is no else clause if a meeting doesn't exist.

I don't think that's related to your issue but it's the first thing that jumped out at me. I took a guess at your intentions with the proc and reset the code using BEGIN/END procs to make it explicit where the blocks are

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[leadfollowup]
@ID AS NVARCHAR(55),
-- this parameter is never used
@NAME AS nvarchar (50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MEETINGS WHERE LEADS_ID = @ID)
    BEGIN 
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        UPDATE 
            MEETINGS 
        SET name = 
            -- this logic probably is incorrect in a concurrent system
            (SELECT TOP 1 FIRST_NAME FROM LEADS ORDER BY DATE_MODIFIED DESC)
            -- this is also probably where you'd use @name parameter
        WHERE  LEADS_ID = @ID

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO 
            MEETINGS 
        (
            LEADS_ID
        ,   NAME
        ) 
        SELECT TOP 1 
            L.ID
        ,   first_name +' '+Last_name +' 'as NAME
        FROM LEADS_CSTM lc
            JOIN LEADS l 
            ON l.id = lc.id_c 
        WHERE 
            FOLLOW_UP_DATE_C >getdate()
        ORDER BY 
            l.date_modified Desc
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with that works... I don't know if its the best answer.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[leadfollowup]
 AS
 Declare @ID NVARCHAR (55)
 set @ID = (Select top 1 ID from leads order by Date_Modified desc)

 Declare @NAME NVARCHAR (50)
 set @NAME = (select top 1 first_name +' '+Last_name +' 'as NAME from leads order by Date_Modified desc)

 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT LEADS_ID FROM MEETINGS WHERE LEADS_ID = (Select top 1 ID from leads order by  Date_Modified desc)
 IF EXISTS(SELECT LEADS_ID FROM MEETINGS WHERE LEADS_ID = @ID )

 BEGIN 

 UPDATE MEETINGS SET name = @NAME WHERE ID = @ID

 END

 ELSE 

 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO MEETINGS (leads_ID,Name) 
 values(@ID,@NAME) 
 END
```